# How to make Chrome stop lowering the toolbar and tabs when hovering MacOS menu bar in fullscreen ? (extension or flag)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

On Chrome, in fullscreen on MacOS 12, whenever I put my mouse on the top edge of the screen, the whole tabs/URL/Bookmark goes down, forcing the web page to adapt. And when I leave the top edge, it goes back up, forcing the web page to adapt again.

Left without hovering (the black space is the notch), right with hovering

[image: Chrome passive]
[image: Chrome hover]

I am looking for an extension (or a flag) that makes it behave like PyCharm (for exemple):

[image: PyCharm passive]
[image: PyCharm hover]

Thanks !

Comment: This is indeed super annoying, hope that somebody has a solution!

Comment: Any working solution here?

Comment: I think Google has solved this since it now works like PyCharm in the example. Maybe make sure to have everything up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by Google !

I am unsure in which exact version but it is working on:
`Version 119.0.6045.123 (Official Build)`

Answer (score 0):

Try Command+Shift+F. It hides the tab bar. But, you can still use Command+Shift+] to navigate tabs.